# Upload files via FTP client from ftp:/remote-dir to ftp:/remote-dir

Tags: linux, ftp

I'm using **ncftpput** to upload local file in my Linux server to FTP.
Is there any way to do the same but move files\directories withing the FTP?
As I've mentioned in the title?

I do aware for the solution of "**ncftp rename**" but it's not good for me as I can't use it in the my bash scripts.

ncftpput is great for upload local files but it's not supporting moving\coping files from **remote-dir** to **remote-dir**.

If you have any equivalent\alternatives for ncftpput please share.

Thanks in advance,
EddieM

Comment: are you only capable of connecting to this server via `ftp` or can you connect using `ssh` as well ?

Comment: The FTP is a windows server. So no, there is not ssh available.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a reason that you didn't disclose, for using ncftp instead of plain ftp, you can do this by using the plain old ftp in a script, as such:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='some.host.name.com'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'
SOURCE='/home/username/file.ext'
TARGET='/var/tmp/file.ext'

ftp $HOST <<EOC
user $USER
$PASSWD
rename $SOURCE $TARGET
quit
EOC

# go on with your bash script from this point on
```

Comment: Hi Mel, it look like something I can work with. I will check it and update. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does it work with moving whole directory? and not only files?

Comment: I believe rename command of ftp only works on single files. You will need to build in some intelligence into the script to do the renaming of all the files in the directory, one by one. It is not an effective method for massive file operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of **[Fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)**

Create 2 fuse directory endpoints based both on an ftp connection and then do regular copy commands or something more complex.

Assume you are using a distro based on apt (but is the same with yum, and so on..)

---

Install the curlftpfs package:

```
apt-get install curlftpfs
```

Create a directory linked to the ftp:

```
mkdir /mnt/ftp1
```

Do the same for the second one:

```
mkdir /mnt/ftp2
```

Connect to the host1 and host2:

```
curlftpfs user1:pass1@host1 /mnt/ftp1
curlftpfs user2:pass2@host2 /mnt/ftp2
```

Do a simple copy command

```
cp -R /mnt/ftp1/somedir /mnt/ftp2
```

When you have finished you can simply unmount the 2 mounts

```
umount /mnt/ftp1
umount /mnt/ftp2
```

---

**Remarks:**
This solution use plain ftp, if you want to take extra advantage of encryption you can use ftps with equivalent commands or in case of shell ftp sftp, but you said that one machine is windows so unless using something like cygwin I guess sftp is out of question.

Comment: Hi, your solution look like an extra effort for my excising solution, but still thanks for the suggestion, I will check it and update!

Comment: Man, discover fuse and you will find your nirvana :P Is super useful to create such kind of complex setups..

Comment: @EddieM excising... you mean existing?